# Windows phone turnstile feather page transition

Tags: windows-phone-7

Silverlight toolkit provides us only with turnstile transition and not turnstile feather.  (The one on the home screen of windows phone 7 where all the tiles flip before the selected one.)

I have looked through the following links and they have not helped me, so I am looking for answers with information not included here:

1. http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-transitions-in-depth--key-concepts-and-api
2. http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2010/10/wp7-page-transitions-sample/
3. http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/03/metro-in-motion-part-2-peel-animations/
4. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117360/Windows-Phone-7-Turnstile-Control-for-Silverlight

Comment: hey someone suggested me using this toolkit [link](http://bewisephonecontrols.codeplex.com), but I dunno how to use it...I've added reference to Bewise.Phone.dll n 
xmlns:Phone="clr-namespace:Bewise.Phone;assembly=Bewise.Phone"
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Bewise.Phone;assembly=Bewise.Phone"
but still I'm unable to use bewise tags :(

Comment: You haven't said what's wrong with the links you have included?

Comment: 1. bewise does nt giveTHAT effect....

Comment: @ColinE I couldn't get much wt these articles were tryna say n I need some kind of tutorial to implement it.....I'm nt into C# so I don't get much of C# code...

Comment: I have successfully used Colin's solution, what seems to be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Windows Phone Toolkit has support for `TurnstyleFeatherTransition`. http://phone.codeplex.com/

Comment: have u tested it ??
is it the turnstile feather that I've mentioned ? 
I'll check it anyways thnxx

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can implement it.

Step 1 => First go to => App.xaml.cs and change your RootFrame to Transition Frame.

```
RootFrame = new TransitionFrame();
```

Step 2 => Go to your page on which you want to implement the `TurnstyleFeatherTransition` Animation and add this Animation Code that enable the TurnstyleFeatherTransition. Put it just before your RootGrid/Root container

```
 <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```

Step 3 => Give feather index to controls. by adding the following code.

```
toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="0"
```

e.g =>

`<Button toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="0" ></Button>`

You are good to go :)